# Display a filtered top-level document library in a subsite?

Tags: 2010, document-library

I got a top level document library with some extra metadata fields such as customer, project etc.

I'd like to create a sub site for each project and include a web part which allows managing of only the project related documents there, such like the document library would be on the subsite instead of the top level site.

How is that possible wich as less effort as possible?

The reason why not each project has its own document library is i.e. sorting for customer and date instead of only for project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ContentByQuery Webpart helps you to populate the documents from multiple sites. To know more about try this link,

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx

But ContentByQuery Webpart only availble in Server edition, If you require for foundation, then use DataForm Webpart.

Using SPDatasource to query the documents from multiple document libraries from multiple sites and using DataForm webpart to populate the queried items.

Answer (score 0):

Try ContentByQuery webpart, this can be used to query data from the root site.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at following post

[How to add doc libraries as web part on child sites..](http://gondals1.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/how-to-add-doc-libraries-as-web-part-on-child-sites/)

If you want to add a doc library on a child site as a web part just to show the content, there are other options like you can use content query web part and show item from different sites but the above link may help you to solve the issue